# how does arp scanning cross the network layer?

Tags: router, subnet, arp

I have the following setup in my network:

```
                                               cc:cc:cc:cc:cc:cc             -------- 192.168.1.5/24 phone     bb:bb:bb:bb:bb:bb
       (other networks and internet) --- 45.53.234.5 router 192.168.1.1/24   -------- 192.168.1.2/24 laptop_2  aa:aa:aa:aa:aa:aa
                                                                             -------- 192.168.1.3/24 laptop_3  
                                                                             -------- 192.168.1.4/24 desktop   dd:dd:dd:dd:dd:dd
```

the router (192.168.1.1/24) is set as the default gateway and is connected to EACH of the 4 devices on the 192.168.1.0/24 subnet through a SEPARATE nic (meaning that each device is on a separate link).

Now, when laptop_2 (192.168.1.2) wants to send something to phone (192.168.1.5), concerning ARP, this happens:

1. laptop_2 looks at the routing table to see where the next hop is and sees that the next hop is 192.168.1.1 through the nic
2. laptop_2 tries to find the mac address of 192.168.1.1 by sending an arp request to ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff with source aa:aa:aa:aa:aa:aa

```
   on the ARP level, the packet will have: 
sender mac : aa:aa:aa:aa:aa:aa
sender ip  : 192.168.1.2
target mac : 00:00:00:00:00:00
target ip  : 192.168.1.1
```

3. the router will reply telling it its mac address cc:cc:cc:cc:cc:cc
4. the router will then do these 3 exact steps with phone 192.168.1.5 and then forward laptop_2's message to it

I analyzed my network with wireshark and all of the above happened.

I then tried running the unix utility `arp-scan` on laptop_2 like this: `arp-scan 192.168.1.0/24`

I assume this utility forces arp packets for network discovery, but according to what i understood it should only be able to discover the default gateway's mac address (cc:cc:cc:cc:cc:cc)

so laptop_2 sends arp requests with source aa:aa:aa:aa:aa:aa and destination ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff

```
on the ARP level, the packets look like this:
sender mac : aa:aa:aa:aa:aa:aa
sender ip  : 192.168.1.2
target mac : 00:00:00:00:00:00
target ip  : 192.168.1.4
```

this packet is repeated 256 times (the target ip changes to each of the 256 addresses in the subnet /24)

since the router doesn't match the ip 192.168.1.4, then it shouldn't answer with anything, or if it has proxy ARP enabled, it should reply with it's own mac address cc:cc:cc:cc:cc:cc

also, i read that arp proxy is a response to a mistake, which is that laptop_2 192.168.1.2 THINKS that it is directly connected to 192.168.1.4 (on the same link), but in reality this isn't the case and shouldn't even send this ARP requestout there.

however, what wireshark shows is that 192.168.1.1 forwards all of these ARP request packets as they are to all of the devices connected to it on the 192.168.1.0/24 subnet (the phone, laptop_3, desktop....) which I can't understand why.

furthermore, desktop 192.168.1.4 even replies to the corresponding one a packet with source dd:dd:dd:dd:dd:dd and destination aa:aa:aa:aa:aa:aa

```
on the ARP level, the packet looks like this:
sender mac : dd:dd:dd:dd:dd:dd
sender ip  : 192.168.1.4
target mac : aa:aa:aa:aa:aa:aa
target ip  : 192.168.1.2
```

this packet is sent to the router and then the router forwards it to laptop_2 192.168.1.2

i can't understand how this is possible since these all devices are connected to the router using separate nics (thus, separate links), and it's impossible for the router to even accept this arp reply because it has destination mac that doesn't even belong to its nic so it should be dropped.

the only scenario i could imagine laptop_1 arp discovering a device other than the gateway is on a bus-topology network where all devices are connected on one single link

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> router (192.168.1.1/... is connected to EACH of the 4 devices on the 192.168.1.0/24 subnet through a SEPARATE nic

Not likely. If you're referring to a consumer router box, these usually contain 1-4 LAN ports that are in fact switched/bridged. The router function attaches to the same switch internally.

If those ports where routed ports, each of them would require a separate IP subnet to be configured. Then, ARP requests wouldn't cross those ports, nor would MAC addresses from another subnet/segment be of any interest.

> the router will reply telling it its mac address cc:cc:cc:cc:cc:cc

No. It's the target node responding - the phone, not the router.

The router itself is actually not involved in a local ARP resolution. It's the switch inside the box that forwards a broadcast ARP request to all LAN ports.

> I then tried running the unix utility arp-scan on laptop_2 like this:
>   arp-scan 192.168.1.0/24
>
> I assume this utility forces arp packets for network discovery, but
>   according to what i understood it should only be able to discover the
>   default gateway's mac address (cc:cc:cc:cc:cc:cc)

That utility tries to resolve all subnet IP addresses in turn. All devices currently connected to the LAN ports (or another switch) should return an ARP reply. It's not limited to the default gateway's IP.

Your confusion is caused by the multitude of functions that are crammed into that extremely common consumer router box. Most contain a router, a DHCP server, a DNS server, a web server, a switch, and a (bridged) wireless access point. Also possible are a DSL modem, a 4G/5G radio, file server for NAS function, SIP gateway, DECT base station, ...

Comment: I understand, so regarding ARP, this device is at least both a router and a switch.

Comment: Thank you very much.

Comment: As a router, it doesn't respond to ARP for any IP it's not configured with. As a switch, it just forwards a broadcast.